# How to disable the Temperature Sensor Si705x

Tags: microcontroller

Is it possible disable Digital Temperature Sensor — Silicon Labs Si705x by software? I want save energy.

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7050-1-3-4-5-A20-1.pdf), I’m observing that the chip comes out of standby only when processing an I2C command or doing a temperature measurement, as commanded via I2C. If you simply don’t send it any I2C commands, it stays in standby and draws only 60nA (typical).

In fact, the front page specifies an average current draw of 195nA when sampling once per second.